# PWA: Do we have to add links to manifest to the header section of all website pages?

Tags: javascript, html, progressive-web-apps

Do we have to add links to manifest to the header section of all pages of my PWA website or just the index.html file?
same question for "metadata".

Answer (score 2):

This is depending on if you are using a SPA (Single Page Application like React or Vue.js) or have overall static files.

For example, if you are using Vue.js, then it is enough to just put it in the index.html.
Frameworks like Nuxt.js, which creates static files in the end, they do it automatically a reference on all `.html` files.

So, if you have static files (like `index.html` and `second.html`) you should always reference to the manifest. Just think about when the user directly gets to the `second.html`, he would not get notified about, that there is a manifest.json like the other metatags.